# Java program is slower as a dist build than when ran from Netbeans

Tags: java, performance, netbeans

So I have this neat physics sim I made that, while running at certain settings, runs at around 34 fps when ran via the Netbeans "run" -command. Then I click "clean and build" and go open the program from the dist folder, and it runs at around 10 fps with the same setup.

Can it be about Java settings? I don't have any special setting done in Netbeans but I'm not sure how to check my the settings on the installed JRE, can they even be different by default from what Netbeans uses by default?

Comment: possibly your memory settings (-Xmx) or maybe you are not using the same version of the JVM.

Comment: Also, did you compile with optimization or with debug flags? How are you measuring the fps? How *exactly* are you executing the compiled application?

Comment: Dist builds are usually faster. Your question does not have enough information for us to help you at the moment. For all we know there could be a native library in the classpath on Netbeans that helps you run code faster Vs the dist build that does not correctly package the native library and falls back on cross-platform code to run the simulation. What more can you tell us about the program ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok problem solved, it was due to outdated Java. I did have my 32 bit Java updated already - the default download at oracle.com but the program was using the 64 bit version, which was actually way outdated. So installing the latest 64 bit release of Java solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's running a different JDK but you can check the JDK that your Netbeans installation is using at Tools -> Java Platforms. To check what version of Java is in use by the distributed version look at your JAVA_HOME, and Path environment variables.

A major difference between the distributed version and the development environment may be the libraries. Check your CLASSPATH environment variable, and compare the actual files between the distribution and development environment to see that the size and dates match. I'm not totally sure how to get at the CLASSPATH used by Netbeans but can advise that it has some special magic it uses based on the libraries included. Also be aware that the order of the included libraries may make a differen

What software are you using to deploy your project?

Comment: @MisterDood I'm afraid, it won't get any better given the (lack of) information in the question.

Comment: Yep I was just providing suggestions as to where he needs to look. There are a total of four potential answers wrapped in one. This is most likely a perfect example of "DLL Hell" where a library is outdated or whatnot. All of my suggestions are worth looking at. Can you think of any other elements that can be different between development and distribution?

Comment: 1. Differences in JDK version.
2. Differences in CLASSPATH (including order of files listed);
3. Differences in the libraries referenced.
4. Somewhat related to #3, often the deployment script (ant, maven, izpack) will modify which files get included and from where.